# Запуск скрипта и сигнал завершения выполнения

Tags: php

Здравствуйте.
Как в PHP запустить скрипт отдельным процессом и получить сигнал о завершении его выполнения? Ну или хотя бы циклом мониторить запущен он сейчас или нет.

Comment: > Как в PHP запустить скрипт отдельным процессом

system(), shell(), pcntl_fork() и все их собратья (nb - форк это совсем отдельная тема, которой лучше не пользоваться без надобности)

> получить сигнал о завершении его выполнения?

В начале скрипта создавать файл lock.tmp, в конце скрипта убивать. Даже не в конце скрипта, а повесить на `register_shutdown_function()`

Comment: может лучше gearman тогда ?

Comment: Gearman это как из пушки по воробьям, советую таки посмотреть на означенный ниже Spotk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если цель этого всего многопоточность, по посмотрите на [Spork](https://github.com/kriswallsmith/spork) и ему подобные фреймворки

Comment: @donkey, скорее многопроцессорность. Нужно следить за количеством выполняемых и выполнять в порядке очереди. Но выполнять именно скрипты.  
Висит демон, который мониторит их таймеры и запускает, если время пришло.

Comment: Я это и имел ввиду, многопоточности ведь как таковой в php нет. Тот же Spork создает процессы. Очереди, колбеки, все это там есть. 

Если нужен именно демон, посмотрите на тот же Gaerman, а может вам больше подойдет RabbitMQ и phpDaemon, гуглите, смотрите что больше подходит под вашу задачу

Answer (score 1):

1. php создает новую «задачу» и получает её id, по которому может узнавать состояние;
2. совершенно отдельный механизм, например, bash скрипт смотрит, есть ли задачи, и запускает выполнение очередной;
3. по окончании выполнения обновляется статус задачи.

Где хранить очередь задач с их id и статусом — да где угодно. Таблица MySQL, Redis, Memcached, Gearman, кролик, текстовый файл в директории.